# How to solve position independent executable error

Tags: android, c

In my android 5.1 handset I'm having this error in all codes with cppdroid 3.3.2.
But I'm facing the problem after updating the latest version. before update it was ok.
I'm a beginner in programing. Please help me.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




int coin[21], make;
long long int dp[21][10000];

long long int ways(  int i,  int a)
{
    if(a <= 0) return 1;
    if(i >= 20) return 0;
    if(dp[i][a] != -1) return dp[i][a];

    long long int ret1 = 0, ret2 = 0;
    if(a - coin[i] >= 0) ret1 = ways(i, a-coin[i]);
    ret2 = ways(i+1, a);

    return dp[i][a] = ret1 + ret2;
}

void make_coins()
{
    int i = 0;
    coin[i] = 1;
    for(i++; i <= 20; i++) coin[i] = (i+1)*(i+1)*(i+1);
    return ;
}

int main(void)
{

    memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
    make_coins();
    while(scanf("%d",&make) == 1) printf("%lld\n", ways(0, make));

    return 0;
}
```

Compillation error:

```
error : only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
```

Comment: Not specifically this code. All the codes I try to compile show this error.

Comment: Looks like it wants you to compile with the flag indicating position-independant code `-fpic`. http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-fpic.htm

Comment: But is it possible with phone? @christian_gibbons

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  Separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like: `i`, `a`, `dp`, `ret1`, `ret2`,  etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 20, 21, 10000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, native code for Android devices has to be compiled with the `-fpic` option, for position-independent code, and linked with the `-pie` option, which tells the linker to produce a position-independent executable (nothing to do with Android 9.0 "Pie").

I'm not familiar with cppdroid, but it presumably has ways to display the options it is using for the compiler and linker? If you still have this problem, and post your lists of options, I may be able to give more specific help.